# gnome-specimen replacement

Tags: 18.04, font-manager

It appears that the font preview tool `gnome-specimen` has been removed from 18.04. A quick search makes it look like it is outdated. Are there an replacement packages that I can use instead? Kfontview is present, but that would require me to pull the entire plasma desktop:

> Command `kfontview` not found, but can be installed with:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install plasma-desktop
> ```

I am not happy to do install another DE (currently using Xfce). I have disk space, but I want to save time when  upgradeing packages 2 DEs => more upgrades to install.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS you can use any tool from list below:

- [**GNOME Font Viewer**](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.6/users-font-viewer.html.uk)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gnome-font-viewer
  ```
- [**GTK+ Font Manager**](https://github.com/FontManager/master)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install font-manager
  ```

  You can launch it with `font-manager`, it looks like:

  [image: <code>font-manager</code>]
- *GWaterfall*

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gwaterfall
  ```

  You can launch it with `waterfall`, it looks like:

  [image: GWaterfall]
- **MATE Font Viewer**

  ```
  sudo apt-get install mate-control-center
  ```

  You can launch it with `mate-font-viewer`, it looks like:

  [image]

Comment: As feedback (for future development, default install etc), I like GTK+ font manager best. It has good and well-exposed features.

Answer (score 4):

After some research I found the best solution: `fontvuer`

Features:

- sample text can be changed
- shows fonts that are available for the script (e.g. cyrillic) that you use

Install by:

```bsh
sudo snap install fontvuer --edge
```

Use by:

```bsh
fontvuer
```

[See details in this very good answer.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/586183)

Comment: Brilliant! thanks mate

Comment: It takes plenty of time to launch if you have many fonts installed, even when installed natively.

Answer (score 0):

[Opcion Font Viewer](http://opcion.sourceforge.net/) allows comparing fonts with custom text, and it only requires Java to work.

[image: screenshot]

For running the jar package, in the terminal enter:

```
java -jar [fileName]
```